# AngularJS and Google OAuth2 redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-api

I'm trying to create a simple application using AngularJS and Google's OAuth2 for authentication.

Due to popup-blocking issues, and mobile friendliness, I decided I wouldn't use the [Google APIs Client Library for JavaScript](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/).

This left me with the option of doing a full redirect to the [OAuth2 endpoint](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth) at google, and redirect users back to my app with the access_token.

I thought this would work just fine. The redirect URI would be 'http://myapp.com/#/register' with an appended 'access_token' query parameter. I would then consume the access_token and direct the user to somewhere else in my app.

This didn't work, as the Google API credentials (http://developers.google.com/console) don't like having a '#' in the Redirect URI's.

I then tried turning off the '#' requirement in URI's by using

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

This didn't work either, because explicitly browsing (in Chrome) to 'http://myapp.com/register' is not recognised by my Angular routes.

Any thoughts on how I should acheive this?

Comment: Are you using url rewriting on your web server to rewrite http://myapp.com/register to http://myapp.com/ ?

Comment: No i'm not, just using bare-bones IIS (as bare as IIS can get anyway :P )

Comment: Seems like you should try that - so that browsing to http://myapp.com/register does work. Then your Angular app handles mapping  the /register to the correct route. Has the additional upside of making your app deep-linkable.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me, with html5 mode set to true in my app.

This code goes into your controller for the redirect page (make sure to inject the $window service):

```
//Get parameters from hash fragment
var params = {};
if ($window.location.hash.indexOf('#') === 0) {
    var regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
    while (m = regex.exec($window.location.hash.substr(1))) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
    }
}

//Validate params, store access token etc.
if (!params.access_token) {
    //...
}
```

If your app doesn't recognise the non-# routes, make sure that your server has the rewrite engine enabled and that you redirect all relevant requests to your angular app main HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IIS, you can install [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extension. Then update your `web.config` file. For example, below config will redirect everything to your Angular app and let it handle the routing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Default" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```